# Form fields not auto summing and multiplying. How can I get this auto working again?

Tags: javascript, forms

This string used to add up the total number of students/dollars and now it isn't working any more.  This isn't my build.

```
<?php
    $i=1;
    while($i <= 5){
?>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="teacher<?php echo $i; ?>">Teacher <?php echo $i; ?>:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="teacher<?php echo $i; ?>" id="teacher<?php echo $i; ?>">
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label for="grade<?php echo $i; ?>">Grade:</label>
            <input type="number" min="0" max="13" name="grade<?php echo $i; ?>" id="grade<?php echo $i; ?>" class="form-control" value="0">
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label for="numStudents<?php echo $i; ?>"># of students:</label>
            <input type="number" min="0" max="100" name="numStudents<?php echo $i; ?>" id="numStudents<?php echo $i; ?>" class="form-control studentsNum" value="0">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
        
<?php $i++;} ?>
        
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="totalStudents">Total # of Students:</label>
            <input type="number" name="totalStudents" id="totalStudents" value="0" min="0" max="100000" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
        
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="pull-right">
            <label for="balanceDue"><span class="text-danger">Bring this amount to the event</span><br>Balance due @ $5/Student:</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
        
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="number" name="balanceDue" id="balanceDue" value="0" min="0" max="10000000" class="form-control">
            <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
            
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
                
        $("input.studentsNum").change(function(){
            var total = Number($("#numStudents1").val()) + Number($("#numStudents2").val()) + Number($("#numStudents3").val()) + Number($("#numStudents4").val()) + Number($("#numStudents5").val());
            $("#totalStudents").val(total);
                                
            var moneytotal = total * 5;
            $("#balanceDue").val(moneytotal);
        });
            
    });
</script>
```

My PHP knowledge is minimal and this is me helping someone, usually this works no problem as the form gets turned on and off depending on the time of year. It is not a huge deal if it sums the student count and multiplies the total but it would be nice if it did.

Comment: Could you edit this question to say what "not working any more" means in detail? What would "working" look like? Be specific.

Comment: To improve this question, you could get the source of the generated PHP page, and show that additionally in your question, as a separate code block. That is the HTML that the jQuery will be operating on.

Comment: Assuming the HTML is generated by PHP okay, this is really a JavaScript question. When a specific input field is amended, it runs some code to recalculate things. To start with, have you opened your browser debug console, to see if you can see any obvious JS errors?

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I will look into these. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Rather than hardcoding the input elements into your JavaScript `change` handler you could make it more flexible by using `querySelectorAll` to return a nodelist of elements that you wish to process and then a basic JavaScript `reduce` function to return a single value which you then output to your chosen display elements.

The following uses basic JavaScript rather than jQuery though no doubt similar methods exist in jQuery.

```js
/*
  a delegated event listener bound to a suitable parent container, here that is the root document.
*/
document.addEventListener('change', e => {
  /*
    inspect the event target to find if this "change" event occcurred on
    one of the designated input elements. If it did find all input elements of
    that same class and use "reduce" to add the values of each element.
  */
  if( e.target instanceof HTMLInputElement && e.target.classList.contains('studentsNum') ) {
    let sum = [ ...document.querySelectorAll('input.studentsNum') ].reduce((a,b)=>a + Number(b.value),0);
    /*
      print the sum and perform other calculations
    */
    document.getElementById('totalStudents').value=sum;
    document.getElementById('balanceDue').value=sum*5;
  }
})
```

```css
.row{margin:1rem}
.row input{width:5rem;}
.row > div{margin:0.1rem;width:30%;display:flex;flex-direction:row;justify-content:space-between}
[type='number'].studentsNum{background:rgba(0,255,0,0.25)}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label for="teacher1">Teacher 1:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="teacher1" id="teacher1">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label for="grade1">Grade:</label>
      <input type="number" min="0" max="13" name="grade1" id="grade1" class="form-control" value="0">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label for="numStudents1"># of students:</label>
      <input type="number" min="0" max="100" name="numStudents1" id="numStudents1" class="form-control studentsNum" value="0">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label for="teacher2">Teacher 2:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="teacher2" id="teacher2">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label for="grade2">Grade:</label>
      <input type="number" min="0" max="13" name="grade2" id="grade2" class="form-control" value="0">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label for="numStudents2"># of students:</label>
      <input type="number" min="0" max="100" name="numStudents2" id="numStudents2" class="form-control studentsNum" value="0">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label for="teacher3">Teacher 3:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="teacher3" id="teacher3">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label for="grade3">Grade:</label>
      <input type="number" min="0" max="13" name="grade3" id="grade3" class="form-control" value="0">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label for="numStudents3"># of students:</label>
      <input type="number" min="0" max="100" name="numStudents3" id="numStudents3" class="form-control studentsNum" value="0">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label for="teacher4">Teacher 4:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="teacher4" id="teacher4">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label for="grade4">Grade:</label>
      <input type="number" min="0" max="13" name="grade4" id="grade4" class="form-control" value="0">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label for="numStudents4"># of students:</label>
      <input type="number" min="0" max="100" name="numStudents4" id="numStudents4" class="form-control studentsNum" value="0">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <label for="teacher5">Teacher 5:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="teacher5" id="teacher5">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label for="grade5">Grade:</label>
      <input type="number" min="0" max="13" name="grade5" id="grade5" class="form-control" value="0">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <label for="numStudents5"># of students:</label>
      <input type="number" min="0" max="100" name="numStudents5" id="numStudents5" class="form-control studentsNum" value="0">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>








<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="totalStudents">Total # of Students:</label>
      <input type="number" name="totalStudents" id="totalStudents" value="0" min="0" max="100000" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <div class="pull-right">
      <label for="balanceDue"><span class="text-danger">Bring this amount to the event</span><br>Balance due @ $5/Student:</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="number" name="balanceDue" id="balanceDue" value="0" min="0" max="10000000" class="form-control">
      <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: THANKS! appreciate the comments and solutions.